# When the divergence of the gradient of a function equals the function

Tags: vectors, harmonic-oscillator

Two questions:

1) What sort of physical process, if any, would a function whose Laplacian (i.e. the divergence of its gradient) equals itself describe? The function is multivariate.

$$\nabla \cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x})$$

In the univariate case, this would reduce to

$$\frac{d^2f(x)}{d x^2}=f(x)$$

meaning that

$$f = \sin(x)$$

2) In the multivariate case, can $f$ also somehow be expressed as sine function(s) of the vector $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: For $\partial_x^2f=f$, hyperbolic functions should be the result (cosh, sinh), not sine & cosine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\nabla \cdot \nabla = \nabla^2$ is the Laplacian operator you are considering the equation $$\nabla^2f=f.$$

This is a special case of Helmholtz equation $$\nabla^2f =\lambda f,$$

for $\lambda =1$. The Helmholtz equation, in turn, is the eigenvalue/eigenvector problem for the Laplace operator $\nabla^2$ and your equation is the one defining the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

It may appear in a variety of contexts. One example is if you take the wave equation $$-\partial_t^2\Psi+\nabla^2\Psi=0$$

and apply separation of variables with $\Psi(t,\mathbf{x})=T(t)f(\mathbf{x})$. In this case you'll get $$\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})}{f(\mathbf{x})}\Longrightarrow\begin{cases}T''(t)&=&\lambda T(t),\\\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})&=&\lambda f(\mathbf{x})\end{cases}$$

for some constant $\lambda$. As you see the spatial part of the separable solutions obeys a Helmholtz equation. Of course the general solution would be a superposition of many such separable solutions. For more examples [check the Wikipedia page on the Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation).

As for the kinds of solution you can expect recall that the equation $$f''(x)=\lambda f(x)$$

has three kinds of solutions depending on the sign of $\lambda$. If $\lambda =0$ the solution is affine, $f(x)=Ax+B$. If $\lambda < 0$ then $\lambda =-\omega^2$ for some $\omega > 0$ and the solution is trigonometric $f(x) = A \cos \omega x + B\sin \omega x$. Finally if $\lambda > 0$ then $\lambda = \omega^2$ for some $\omega > 0$ and the solution hyperbolic $f(x)=A\cosh \omega x+B\sinh\omega x$. Your case which is $\lambda =1$ falls into the third category giving hyperbolic solutions.

Notice that either $\sin(\omega x)$ and $\cos(\omega x)$, if differentiated twice, produce a negative sign.

Comment: This is a rather long winded way to say OPs assumption of some is wrong.

Comment: That should say sine, not some. Stupid autocorrect.

Comment: @user1620696 Thanks. In the second equation of your answer, how is it possible to find the eigenvector and eigenvalue $\lambda$? I only know how to do this when the equation is of the form $Ax=\lambda x$, where $A$ and $x$ are a matrix and vector, respectively; whereas the Helmholtz equation is a scalar equation.

Comment: @KyleKanos that's true. I've tried also to address OP's question about where his equation might appear.

Comment: @ben what you ask I consider to be a separate question on its own. But a possible short answer is that you solve the differential equation with some boundary conditions and finds what values of $\lambda$ yield non-trivial solutions. You will find a basis of eigenfunctions spanning the space of compatible solutions and the associated eigenvalues. Look for the so-called Sturm-Liouville problem. In some cases there are some smart tricks that makes this task easier. These are often presented in QM textbooks like Cohen-Tannoudji, when dealing, e.g., with the quantum harmonic oscillator.